# Passing a strings from .env.local on new Redis instance giving an error

Tags: typescript, next.js, redis

I have got a problem with a typescript when creating a new Redis instance. I have created an .env.local file with the same names for redis url and token.

Following code below

```js
import { Redis } from "@upstash/redis";

// @ts-ignore
export const db: Redis = new Redis({
    url: process.env.UPSTASH_REDIS_REST_URL,
    token: process.env.UPSTASH_REDIS_REST_TOKEN
})
```

Is giving me this typescript error:

```
 TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 2 of 2, '(requesters: Requester): Redis', gave the following error.     Argument of type '{ url: string | undefined; token: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Requester'.       Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'url' does not exist in type 'Requester'.
```

I have been following the upstash/redis documentation, the code is working but the following error is kinda annoying

I have tried the Webstorm actions from preventing the ts errors but still didnt work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really weird, cause it should work

as a quick workaround, can you try:

```
export const db = Redis.fromEnv()
```

This will automatically load the variables from your environment and bypasses the constructor

Comment: Thank you! It does work but still, why does typescript behave like that? But anyway's thank you for the solution

Answer (score 1):

Today I also came across this error,
But I was able to resolve this error.

You can use this code :

```
import { Redis } from '@upstash/redis';

export const db: Redis = new Redis({
   url: process.env.UPSTASH_REDIS_REST_URL || '',
   token: process.env.UPSTASH_REDIS_REST_TOKEN || ''
});
```

It really works.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't comment on Ugur Eren's answer, but what you showed is exactly what `Redis.fromEnv()` does :)

Comment: It may be, I'm not familiar with the upstash, but i just wanted to give an answer according to the OP's question. If it does the same thing, your answer is much more better and should be used.

Comment: Oh well, it is really the exact same thing. https://github.com/upstash/upstash-redis/blob/main/platforms/nodejs.ts#L152

Answer (score 0):

I know this is coming late. But for others coming across this error, Typescript is unsure if the env variable will have a value so its typed as `string | undefined`. Simply add a bang at the end of the variable. [See here for more details](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator).

```
export const db: Redis = new Redis({
   url: process.env.UPSTASH_REDIS_REST_URL!,
   token: process.env.UPSTASH_REDIS_REST_TOKEN!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is displayed when no variable with the mentioned names is defined in env files. **Alternatively** you can define them in `next.config.mjs`:

```js
const nextConfig = {
  env: {
    VARIABLE_NAME: 'value',
    UPSTASH_REDIS_REST_URL: 'https://...',
  }
};
```

This ensures variables are accessible in `process.env`.

### Local Redis REST API

Suppose you don't want your software to connect to a third-party server like Upstash for some reason. You can install Webdis which is REST API that is founded on a Redis base server. The only requirement is to have the Redis server installed and running.
https://github.com/nicolasff/webdis